# AWS Redirect one domain to another except one path leading to a static website hosted on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a website with a normal url and a shorthand url, which is redirected to the normal/long url using an AWS EC2 Application load balancer, switching to http to https in the process.

Now I want one singular URL path, when added to the shorthand url, not the long url, to lead to an entirely different website.
Here an example:

```
short.url -> long.url (-> my website)  
short.url/randompath -> long.url/randompath  
short.url/specificpath -> short.url/specificpath -> entirely different website served from my s3 bucket  
long.url/specificpath -> probably some 404 error
```

For context, Im doing this as I currently dont have full access to the website source, so I cant add the new website there directly.

Would it make sense at all to do this, is this even possible? As an alternative I'm thinking about creating a subdomain for my s3 bucket and doing a basic load balancer redirect to it, so `short.url/specificpath -> sub.short.url/specificpath`.

Thanks for your answers already!

Comment: "Would it make sense at all to do this, is this even possible?" Yes, why not? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: My problem here is mostly, that in the Load Balancer I cannot redirect to an aws s3 bucket, and aws s3 buckets seemingly can only be staticly hosted when an index.html is present in the root directory, and then I dont know how to directly link sub paths and how I would have to configure my Route53 and CloudFront to point my short.url to both the load balancer and the s3 bucket seemingly at the same time.

Comment: Ah OK, I missed the part about one path needing to be on S3. Yes you will need to use CloudFront for that, and configure multiple origins in CloudFront.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your pointer got me to look at Cloud Front Behaviours more closely, which are exactly what I need!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.